# How to select row using array of object in NodeJs

Tags: mysql, node.js, select

I have database with game square (called game):

```
id | x | y | isGold
```

I program I have array of coords like this:

```
var test = [
 {x:1, y:2},
 {x:2, y:4}
]
```

I want select all rows from game table somethink like this:

```
Select * from game where x and y in (?) where isGold = true, [test] ...
```

But problem is, that I don't know how to create select with object. I can transform my array to anything, how can I make a query for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you use mysqljs/mysql npm package try this:

```
Select * from game where (x, y) IN (?) where isGold = true, [[[1, 2], [2, 4]]
```

Look at the doc
https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#performing-queries

> Arrays are turned into list, e.g. ['a', 'b'] turns into 'a', 'b'
>   Nested arrays are turned into grouped lists (for bulk inserts), e.g.
>   [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']] turns into ('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')